# select count of rows from 2 tables and merge into one row (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, union

i create a web app like facebook by php and mysqli

in my app i have a table for posts , one table for likes , and one table for comments

i want to get the number of comments and likes of each post in one row with his post_id!!!

i try some querys likes this :

```
select `tblpost`.`post_id`,  COALESCE(TCOMM.`comment_num`,0) as `c_num`, COALESCE(TLIKE.`like_num`,0) as `l_num`
from 
(select `tblpost`.`post_id`, count(*) as `like_num` from `tblpost` join `tbllikes` on `tbllikes`.`post_id` = `tblpost`.`post_id` group by `tblpost`.`post_id`
) TLIKE
inner join
(select `tblpost`.`post_id`, count(*) as `comment_num` from `tblpost` join `tblcomments` on `tblcomments`.`post_id` =  `tblpost`.`post_id` group by `tblpost`.`post_id`) TCOMM
on
    TCOMM.`post_id` = TLIKE.`post_id`
```

but i don't know what's my problem

Comment: We do not know your problem either. Mind telling us what you expect as a result, and what you indeed get :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do count distincts with two left joins.

Something like this would work if there are fields `like_id` and `comment_id` in the tables `tbllikes` and `tblcomments`

```
SELECT 
    tblpost.post_id AS post_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT tbllikes.like_id) AS likes,
    COUNT(DiSTINCT tblcomments.comment_id) AS comments
FROM tblpost 
LEFT JOIN tbllikes ON tbllikes.post_id = tblpost.post_id
LEFT JOIN tblcomments on tblcomments.post_id =  tblpost.post_id
GROUP BY tblpost.post_id
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you can greatly simplify your query:

```
select l.post_id,
        COALESCE(c.comment_num, 0) as c_num, COALESCE(l.like_num, 0) as l_num
from  (select l.post_id, count(*) as like_num
       from tbllikes l 
       group by l.post_id
      ) l inner join
      (select c.post_id, count(*) as comment_num
       from tblcomments c
       group by c.post_id
      ) c
      on l.post_id = c.post_id;
```

This will only get you posts that have both likes and comments.  To get what you want, use a `left join`:

```
select p.post_id,
      COALESCE(c.comment_num, 0) as c_num, COALESCE(l.like_num, 0) as l_num
from tblpost p left join
     (select l.post_id, count(*) as like_num
      from tbllikes l 
      group by l.post_id
     ) l
     on l.post_id = p.post_id left join
     (select c.post_id, count(*) as comment_num
      from tblcomments c
      group by c.post_id
     ) c
     on c.post_id = p.post_id;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(c.`comment_num`, 0) as `c_num`, COALESCE(l.`like_num`, 0) as `l_num`
from tblpo' at line 2